# Converting "ppp" to multitype

Tags: r, spatstat

I have been running two unmarked planar point pattern data sets through a series of spatstat functions. Now I would like to use the Kcross.inhom function to describe interaction between the two, but Kcross only works with marked data, so I have combined all x-y data into one csv file and added a column that distinguishes the two. I have established the following point pattern object, but do not understand how to edit the subsequent example of Kcross for my purposes. Or, perhaps there is a better way? Thanks for your help!

```
# read in data & create ppp
collisionspotholes<-read.csv("cpmulti.csv")
cp<-ppp(collisionspotholes[,3],collisionspotholes[,4],c(40.50390735,40.91115166),c(-74.25262139,-73.7078596))

# synthetic example
pp <- runifpoispp(50)
pp <- pp %mark% factor(sample(0:1, npoints(pp), replace=TRUE))
K <- Kcross(pp, "0", "1")
K <- Kcross(pp, 0, 1) # equivalent
```

Comment: Packages you are using, please.

Comment: I'm using spatstat. I've loaded spdep, too, but I don't think I'm using any of its functions.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really clear as to what the problem is that you are having.  You seem to me to "be there" essentially.  However let me, for completeness, spell out the procedure that you should follow:

Let X and Y be your two point patterns (observed, presumably, in the *same* window).

Put these together into a single pattern:

`XY <- superimpose(X=X,Y=Y)`

Note that there is no need to dick around with your csv files; it is much more efficient to use the facilities provided by spatstat.

The foregoing syntax produces a multitype point pattern with marks being a factor with levels "X" and "Y".  (If you want the levels to be denoted by other symbols you can easily arrange this.)

Then just calculate the inhomogeneous Kcross function:

`Ki <- Kcross.inhom(XY,"X","Y")`

That is all that there is to it.

Note that the foregoing uses the *default* method of estimating the intensities of the two patterns, explicitly leave-one-out kernel smoothing with bandwidth chosen by `bw.diggle()`. There may be better ways of estimating the intensities, perhaps by fitting a parametric model.  This depends on the nature of the information available to you.

*Interpreting* the output of `Kcross.inhom()` is, IMHO, subtle and difficult.
Be cautious in any conclusions that you draw.

Answer (score 2):

Rolf Turner's answer is correct. However, you say that

> I have combined all x-y data into one csv file and added a column that distinguishes the two.

OK, suppose the data frame is called `df` and it has columns named `x` and `y` giving the spatial coordinates and `h` which is a character vector identifying whether the corresponding point is a pothole (`h="p"`) or a collision (`h="c"`). Then you could do

```
X <- ppp(df$x, df$y, xlim, ylim, marks=factor(df$h))
```

where `xlim, ylim` are the limits for the spatial coordinates. Or more elegantly

```
X <- with(df, ppp(x, y, xlim, ylim, marks=factor(h))
```

Note the use of `factor` to ensure that the marks are categorical values. Then type

```
X
```

to check that you've got a 'multitype point pattern'.

Then you can do, e.g.

```
K <- Kcross(X)
Ki <- Kcross.inhom(X)
```

Please read the help files for `Kcross, Kcross.inhom` for advice about how to use these functions and how to interpret the results.

Incidentally, please do not send the same question to multiple forums at the same time. That is difficult for those who have to answer.